# Need help installing zulu-8

Tags: software-installation

I keep getting "package zulu-8 has no installation candidate after importing the key and adding the package to the repository and running sudo apt-get install zulu-8? Help. Also tried installing via a zip file and no luck there either!
I have spent hours on linux journey and learned a ton but still no luck...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also.
I think it was because I was trying to install it on **32-bit** Bodhi 4.5.0. Once I switched to the **64-bit** Bodhi 4.5.0 I was able to install zulu-8 with no problem.